# JS Graphs using positive & negative values (Single line graph)

Tags: javascript, jquery, graph, highcharts

I want to integrate graph into my website with positive & negative values. If the value is negative then It will go into a red section, if no is positive then it will go into green section.

Right now I am unable to find such type of graph library in javascript, what will be the exact name of this type of graph?

Please let me know the solution.

Comment: When I don't know the name of a type of chart or graph, I usually browse the examples on the [D3 gallery](https://github.com/d3/d3/wiki/Gallery), and usually end up with something.

Comment: There is a lot of examples, can you please share a specific example, that fulfills my requirements.

Comment: I was simply pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I'll check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create this type of chart by using Highcharts. Please check the example below:

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        inverted: true,
        height: 80,
        events: {
            load: function() {
                var yAxis = this.yAxis[0],
                    y = this.plotTop + this.plotHeight / 2,
                    center = yAxis.toPixels(0);

                this.renderer.path([
                    'M', this.plotLeft, y, 'L', center, y
                ]).attr({
                    'stroke-width': 1,
                    stroke: 'red'
                }).add();

                this.renderer.path([
                    'M', center, y, 'L', this.plotSizeY + this.plotLeft, y
                ]).attr({
                    'stroke-width': 1,
                    stroke: 'green'
                }).add();
            }
        }
    },
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        tickPositions: [-18, 0, 27],
        gridLineWidth: 2
    },
    xAxis: {
        visible: false
    },
    series: [{
        type: 'scatter',
        data: [21],
        marker: {
            fillColor: 'orange',
            radius: 10
        }
    }]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/x9vo0tr6/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Answer (score 1):

The closest name I've found is just a "number line", and it looks like [this JavaScript library](https://github.com/jsxgraph/jsxgraph) has a specific example of it:

https://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/wiki/index.php/Number_line

But I think in general you're better off building a custom one-dimensional plot of sorts, with [D3.js](https://d3js.org/), for example.